# Не работает функция в bash

Tags: linux, bash

Необходимо чтобы после того как пользователь ввел Prefix, сразу срабатывала function menu и выводило меню пользователю. Работать function menu должна через case без каких либо дополнительных  команд для вызова функции меню - не могу понять как это сделать ???

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "введите PREFIX: "
read Slov  # в переменную Slov попадает слово которое ввел пользователь
Prefix=("$Slov")    # в этой переменной храниться слово для сравнениz]я


function new_dir {  #функция в которой мы создаем новую директорию с актуальной датой
YMD=$(pwd)/$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
mkdir -p $YMD
}


function New_files {  #функция которая создает 100 файлов (имена файлов от 1 до 100) и в каждом файле лежит 4-х значное число
for i in {1..100};    #создаем файлы
do echo  $(( $RANDOM % 8999 + 1000 )) > $YMD/File$i; done   #рандомно создаем числа сохраняем их в вновь созданный файл
cat $YMD/* | while read y  #просмотр содержимого файлов из папки
do
echo "$y" >> $YMD/s    #выводит содержимое на экран, сохраняем все числа из созданных файлов File$i в файл s
done
}
echo "$y"


function menu {  #функция в которой мы вызываем меню в котором пользователю предлагаются варианты действий
for i in 1; do
if [[ "$Slov" = "$Prefix" ]]; then   #здесь мы сравниваем введенное слово с тем что должно быть
    #echo "cool"   # программа может продолжать работать
echo "Введите 0: программа выполнит все действия"
echo "Введите 1: программа выполнит только 1 действие - создаст с 100 файлов с рандомными 4-х значными числами"
echo "Введите 2: программа выполнит только 2 действие - выдаст сумму первых 50 чисел и вторых  50 чисел, а такще покажет како"
echo "Введите 3: программа выполнит только 3 действие - программа скажет в каком файле лежит самое большое и самое маленькое"
else
    exit 1  #в случае если слово введено неверно скрипт полностью прекращает работу
fi
done

echo -n "введите номер операции: "  #здесь мы вводим номер операции которую хотим выполнить
read Nomer
}


case $Slov in
        "1")
         menu
         new_dir
         New_files
         ;;
esac
```

Comment: `после того как пользователь ввел Prefix, сразу срабатывала function menu` — ну так вызывайте эту функцию сразу «после того как…». только описание функции переместите выше её вызова.

Comment: Пропишите выше case вызов функции меню, а из кейса его уберите

Comment: Честно говоря не совсем понятно как это сделать. возможно вы имеете ввиду case $Slov in 
menu 
"1")
         new_dir
         New_files
         ;;
esac

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1361247/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-case-%d0%b2-bash-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83)